# How to remove the space between left margin and ToC?

Tags: table-of-contents

I have been working on a thesis file. I had two specific issues.

1. extra space between the left margin and ToC as shown in the figure
   [image: ToC with extra extra space between left margin and ToC]
2. extra space between the left margin and LoF & LoT

I solved the second issue by making `\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}` to `\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}` as shown in the code below.
But for the first issue of ToC, I haven't found any solution yet.

```
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\@dottedtocline
{\leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern\@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern\@dotsep mu$}}
{}
{}{\fail}

% enlarge label width
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{4em}}
\renewcommand*\l@table{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{5em}}
\makeatother
```

An MWE is given below

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}


%%--------------Basic Packages------------%%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts} 
\usepackage[top=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm, left=3.56cm, right=2.54cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[labelfont=bf, labelsep=space]{caption} 
%\usepackage[belowskip=4pt, labelformat=simple]{subcaption} 

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}



\usepackage{titletoc} % Chapter title formatting in ToC
\titlecontents{chapter}[17pt]{\vskip8pt}{\fontsize{14}{16.8}\selectfont\bfseries\MakeUppercase{chapter}~\thecontentslabel\quad}{\bfseries}{\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}[\vskip5pt]




\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\chapter{Introduction}
    \section{Introduction}
    \lipsum[2-3]
    \begin{figure}[!htb]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image}
        \caption{Light Clock}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[!htb]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image}
        \caption{Light Clock}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[!htb]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image}
        \caption{Light Clock}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed `17pt` in `\titlecontents{chapter}[17pt]...` to `0pt`, and added

```tex
\dottedcontents{section}[2.3em]{}{2.3em}{1pc}
\dottedcontents{figure}[2.3em]{}{2.3em}{1pc}
\dottedcontents{table}[2.3em]{}{2.3em}{1pc}
```

Full example

```tex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}


%%--------------Basic Packages------------%%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts} 
\usepackage[top=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm, left=3.56cm, right=2.54cm]{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
%\usepackage[labelfont=bf, labelsep=space]{caption} 
%\usepackage[belowskip=4pt, labelformat=simple]{subcaption} 

%\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}



\usepackage{titletoc} % Chapter title formatting in ToC
\titlecontents{chapter}[0pt]{\vskip8pt}{\fontsize{14}{16.8}\selectfont\bfseries\MakeUppercase{chapter}~\thecontentslabel\quad}{\bfseries}{\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}[\vskip5pt]

\dottedcontents{section}[2.3em]{}{2.3em}{1pc}
\dottedcontents{figure}[2.3em]{}{2.3em}{1pc}
\dottedcontents{table}[2.3em]{}{2.3em}{1pc}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\chapter{Introduction}
    \section{Introduction}
    \lipsum[2-3]
    \begin{figure}[!htb]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image}
        \caption{Light Clock}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[!htb]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image}
        \caption{Light Clock}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[!htb]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image}
        \caption{Light Clock}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It actually works. But I don't understand why I added this 17pt here. This is the reason why I couldn't find the solution. Thanks again.

Comment: I only changed the 17pt to 0pt. Nothing elese

Comment: With `titletoc` loaded, it's better to use commands/interfaces from this package to configure list-of styles, instead of directly redefining `\l@figure` etc.